# Reference request for an English translation of a book of Tate

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, l-functions

In [this](https://www.icts.res.in/program/ECL2021) ongoing program, Professor Mahesh Kakde said that the best reference for learning about Stark and Gross-Stark conjecture is [this](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780817631888) book of John Tate. But this book is in French. Is there any English translation for it?

Comment: MathSciNet doesn't seem to be aware of any published translation, nor is there one in the *Collected Works* edited by Mazur and Serre.

Comment: Yes. But sometimes someones do an informal translation for something. I hope there exists such a translation.